# How to calculate the percentage of the difference between two 2D arrays?

Tags: matlab, distance, percentage, similarity

Let's presume that:

Array 1 = [ 1 4 5 6 8 ; 2 4 5 7 8]

Array 2 = [ 2 4 5 3 5 ; 0 5 6 3 2]

the distance between them is

Distance = |X2 - X1|

Distance = [1 0 0 3 3 ; 2 1 1 4 6]

how to find the percentage of this difference?

1. if Distance is high, it means that the two arrays are not similar to each other (low percentage),
2. if Distance is low it it means that the arrays are closely similar to each other (high percentage),
3. and if Distance is Zeros it means that the two arrays are similar to each other.

Comment: While this may be a general programming question. You may have more luck if you specify which language you are trying to solve the problem in.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in matlab

Comment: not sure but i guess the values of Array 2. The reason is because i want to find how similar is Array 1 to Array 2 by percentage.